# Graphics.drawRect being filled

Tags: java, swing, graphics, rectangles

I'm making a rectangle selector using the mouse, and i have a normal `drawRect` rectangle surrounding it. When the width or height goes negative, The Rectangle is filled. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Pie extends JPanel{
  public boolean running = true;
  public Rectangle mouseRect;
  public Rectangle rectBounds;
  public int x1,y1,x2,y2;
  public boolean showRect = false;

 public Pie(){
     setFocusable(true);
     MAdapter mama = new MAdapter();
     setDoubleBuffered(true);
     this.addMouseListener(new MAdapter());
     this.addMouseMotionListener(mama);
     setBackground(Color.black);
     Thread update = new Thread(){
         public void run(){
             while(running){
                 repaint();
                 try{Thread.sleep(2);}catch(InterruptedException e){}
             }
         }
     };
     update.start();
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g);           
     //if(y2 < y1) y2 = y1;                  
     if(showRect){
         g.setColor(new Color(0,250,0,50));
         g.fillRect(x1,y1,x2 - x1,y2 - y1);
         g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0));            
         g.drawRect(x1 - 1,y1 - 1,x2 - x1 + 1,y2 - y1 + 1);
     }
 }

 class MAdapter extends MouseAdapter{
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            showRect = true;
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();
        }
     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        x2 = e.getX();
        y2 = e.getY();
        rectBounds = new Rectangle(x1,y1,x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
     }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
            showRect = false;
            rectBounds = new Rectangle(x1,y1,x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
            x1 = 0;
            y1 = 0;
            x2 = 0;
            y2 = 0;
        }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
     JFrame f = new JFrame("Aber");
     f.setSize(500,500);
     f.setResizable(true);
     f.setVisible(true);
     f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     f.add(new Pie());
   }
 }
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Good question, with an SSCCE, but not a great answer. What if you want to change your program so that it now allows the user to drawn multiple rectangles, and allow the user to select and even remove drawn rectangles? It is much easier to do this by using Rectangle or Rectangle2D objects for this purpose, trust me.

Comment: I don't know if there is a hard and fast rule that states that the width/height must be >= 0, but as you've discovered, when it comes to painting, it will make a difference

Answer (score 3):

You're use of a Thread and repaint is wrong and unnecessary. Please get rid of that portion of your code and instead simply call repaint in the MouseListener. Use `Math.abs(...)`, `Math.min(...)` and `Math.max(...)` to help you draw better behaved rectangles. For example,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Pie2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = 500;
   private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.black;
   private static final Color RECT_COLOR = Color.green;
   private static final Color RECT_FILL_COLOR = new Color(0,250,0,50);
   private Rectangle2D rect = null;

   public Pie2() {
      setBackground(BACKGROUND);
      MyMouseAdapater mouseAdapater = new MyMouseAdapater();
      addMouseListener(mouseAdapater);
      addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapater);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public void setRect(Rectangle2D rect) {
      this.rect = rect;
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (rect != null) {
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
         g2.setColor(RECT_FILL_COLOR);
         g2.fill(rect);
         g2.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
         g2.draw(rect);
      }
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapater extends MouseAdapter {
      private Point p1;

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            return;
         }
         p1 = e.getPoint();
         drawRect(p1);
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         if (p1 == null) {
            return;
         }
         drawRect(e.getPoint());
      }

      private void drawRect(Point p2) {
         int x = Math.min(p1.x, p2.x);
         int y = Math.min(p1.y, p2.y);
         int w = Math.abs(p1.x - p2.x);
         int h = Math.abs(p1.y - p2.y);         

         Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
         Pie2.this.setRect(rect);
         Pie2.this.repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            return;
         }
         drawRect(e.getPoint());

      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Pie2 mainPanel = new Pie2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pie2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

With the key code being here:

```
  private void drawRect(Point p2) {
     int x = Math.min(p1.x, p2.x);
     int y = Math.min(p1.y, p2.y);
     int w = Math.abs(p1.x - p2.x);
     int h = Math.abs(p1.y - p2.y);         

     Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
     Pie2.this.setRect(rect);
     Pie2.this.repaint();
  }
```

Note the use of the Math library methods to do your calculations regardless of where the first Point is in relation to the second Point.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody thanks for your answers, but ive decided its easier to just make a border with lines this way:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g);                        
     if(showRect){
         g.setColor(new Color(0,250,0,50));
         g.fillRect(x1,y1,x2 - x1,y2 - y1);
         g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0));            
         g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1);
         g.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2);
         g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y2);
         g.drawLine(x2, y1, x2, y2);

     }

 }
```